# get all records with same column value in an sqlite db table using moor_flutter package

Tags: flutter, dart, android-sqlite, flutter-moor

I have a table called contacts. I want to get all records `where person_id = 1` in **contacts** table below.

```dart
class Contacts extends Table {
  IntColumn get id => integer().autoIncrement()();
  TextColumn get contact_type => text().withLength(min: 1, max: 50)();
  TextColumn get contact => text().withLength(min: 1, max: 100)();
  IntColumn get person_id =>
      integer().customConstraint('REFERENCES persons(id)')();
  DateTimeColumn get created => dateTime()();
  DateTimeColumn get updated => dateTime()();
}
```

How do I perform `select * from contacts where person_id = 1` using [moor_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/moor_flutter)? thank you, posted with Love.

Comment: No I'm using [moor_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/moor_flutter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a look to the [docs](https://moor.simonbinder.eu/docs/getting-started/writing_queries/).

You are looking for something like this :

```dart
@UseMoor(tables: [Contacts])
class MyDatabase extends _$MyDatabase {  

    Future<List<Contact>> getContactByPersonId(int id) {
        return (select(contacts)..where((c) => c.person_id.equals(id))).get();
    }
}
```